# How to parse category term from Wordpress ATOM feed in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, feed, atom-feed

I have a standard ATOM feed from a Wordpress instance.  In the feed, the following category items appear:

```
<category scheme="http://alpha-s2new.simplescienceinc.com/blog" term="Blog" />
<category scheme="http://alpha-s2new.simplescienceinc.com/blog" term="Mobile" />
<category scheme="http://alpha-s2new.simplescienceinc.com/blog" term="Websites" />
```

I'm using the following code to parse the feed:

```
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
    $item = array(
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('updated')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'author' => $node->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'postid' => $node->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'cats' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
```

As you can see.. the last item pulls the "category" node.  But it returns an empty string.  And I think I know why.  So the question is..  what's the syntax to actually pull the terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`term` is an attribute, so you need to use `getAttribute` to get the data from it. For example:

```
// $dom is the DOMDocument object holding the XML
$cats = $dom->getElementsByTagName('category');
foreach ($cats as $c) {
    echo "term: " . $c->getAttribute('term') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
term: Blog
term: Mobile
term: Websites
```

If you're using `$c->nodeValue`, you won't get anything because the node doesn't have a value--it's empty. To get the first category's term attribute, you'll need to substitute your current line with this:

```
'cats' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->getAttribute('term')
```